# How to create a data extension based on unopens of a send (Exacttarget)

Tags: dataextensions

I want to target contacts who did not open a specific send. I want to create a data extension of this and send to that data extension. I cannot figure out how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a MINUS query between _Sent data view and _Open data view. Store the result in a Data Extension and that is your list of UnOpens.

[Query Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: Is there no easier way to achieve this?

Comment: That is the only way!